# Program not coutting

Tags: c++, cout

I am using th following code but it only asks me for a input and closes without couting my input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 


using namespace std;

int main(){
    int balance=0;
    int withdraw=0;
    char* str;
    cin.getline(str,10);
    cout<<str;  
    withdraw=atoi(strtok(str," "));
    balance=atoi(strtok(NULL," "));
    cout<<withdraw<<" "<<balance;

    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char* str;
```

This only gives you a pointer. That pointer doesn't point anywhere, especially not at some `char`s that you can write to. When you call `cin.getline(str,10)`, it tries to write to where this pointer is pointing to. That gives you undefined behaviour. An easy fix for this is to make `str` an array of `10` `char`s:

```
char str[10];
```

However, I recommend that you start using `std::string` instead and figure out how to do `strtok`-like operations with a `std::string`. Hint: look at [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory for `str`.

```
char *str = new char[10];
```

otherwise using uninitialized pointer will invoke **undefined behavior**. And call `delete` to free the allocated memory once you done with `str`.

```
delete[] str;
```

Instead of using `char *`, it is better to use [`std::string`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(C%2B%2B)).

Comment: Recommending `malloc` in C++ is not recommended.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka; Can't deny.

Comment: 13 21 C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\main.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: @JosephMansfield; Why?

Comment: @haccks With `new[]`, you need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield; Yes. :)